# "to drive around" implies who is driving the vehicle?

Tags: synonyms

In the sentence "I drive the car", I am controlling the car. If I am not driving, I could say, for instance, "I ride the car".

edit: I meant "I ride *in* the car"

Could "to drive around in" mean both or necessarily just one of them? Examples:

- I am driving around in my car (I am driving)
- My mother drives around in (the?) bus every day (Does she drive?)

Comment: In principle you could say your mother ***is driven around** [in a bus, taxi, whatever]*, but most people would probably say she ***rides around***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  They'd probably say it in an answer.

Comment: When the subject is plural (_We're driving around/They're driving around_) , it means that we or they are all riding, but one unspecified person is doing the driving.

Comment: @puppetsock: *Most* people might do that. But ***I*** said it by way of complementing my "migrate to ELL" closevote.

Comment: We normally speak of riding _in_ a car. However, definitions of _drive_ include _be transported in a motor vehicle_; it doesn't have to refer only to the driver.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, could you give an example of that definition?

Comment: https://www.thefreedictionary.com/drive
under 'Verb intransitive 3b'

Comment: @Kate Bunting it seems to me that one person of the group is driving the car in this example (We all got in the car and drove to the supermarket). AFAIK "to drive" can only be used when at least one member of the subject is driving. For instance, the following sentence would not make sense: We all got in the taxi/subway and drove to the supermarket". Right?

Comment: @Alan Evangelista So essentially the AHD definition isn't detailed enough (though note that their example involves multiple occupancy, with the probability that one of those 'riding' is doing the driving). //  It will be fun to see where the language goes when driverless cars become more common.

Comment: "We all got in the taxi and drove to …" would be acceptable to me. I don't think anyone would speak of 'driving somewhere' in a train, which can only travel between stations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: "to drive around" implies that the subject is driving the vehicle. When the subject is plural, one person of the set is driving. Examples:

- I drive around in that bus every day (I am the bus driver)
- We drove around in my Ferrari last Sunday. (one of us is the driver)

"to ride around" does not imply who is driving the vehicle, thus it may be used when the subject is not the driver. Examples:

- I rode around in that bus yesterday (the bus driver is me or someone else)
- We rode around in my Ferrari last Sunday (the driver is one of us or someone else)

The same applies for "to drive" and "to ride".

Answer (score 0):

> I ride the car

This is awkward because you're not describing what you're doing with the car. 
Most people would assume you rode *in* the car, but maybe [you like living dangerously](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WSD4Wfd-hPk) and rode on the roof. Ride(rode) does generally exclude you from driving, however. A better phrase here is

> I rode in the car

Cars are a bit of an exception, though, because it is equally common to both drive and ride in cars, so you must qualify which you are doing. In most other cases, mentioning ride(rode) as your verb is enough to communicate what you are doing

> My mother rides the bus

This is generally understood and acceptable because few people actually drive public transportation. If you are a bus driver, you have to add the qualification that you are, in fact, driving, or it will be assumed you are merely a rider.

> I drive a bus around for work

It would be uncommon, then, for you to say your mother drove a bus. If you did, people would assume she is a professional bus driver.

Comment: Nice explanation about "to ride (in)", but my question was about "to drive around in". Are they synonyms?

Comment: The latter part of my answer covers that. `To drive around in a bus` implies you are the driver, not merely a rider.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista To specifically answer your question (which was not actually done in the answer), if your mother ***drives*** *around in the bus*, then *she* drives the bus. But if your mother ***rides*** *around in the bus*, then she is a passenger and somebody *else* is driving the bus. The two are not synonymous, aside from the fact that both descriptions involve somebody inside the bus in some capacity.